# Unable to Run tests using Runner in Intellij

Tags: java, selenium, testing, intellij-idea, cucumber

When trying to run test using the runner for a test I creating for a feature file. The runner is build and completed successfully but nothing happens.

Feature File:

```
Feature: Login to Queries

  #Login in Chrome
Scenario: Login using Chrome
Given I open Chrome
When I browse to Queries
Then I login to Queries using "pcy1" and "123"£"
```

Step Definition (this class extends the base class):

```
public class login extends base {

@Given("^I open Chrome$")
public void iOpenChrome() throws Throwable {
    driver = initializeDriver();
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I browse to Queries$")
public void iBrowseToQueries() {
    driver.get("https://atesting321.test/");
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I login to Queries using \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"£\"$")
public void iLoginToQueriesUsingAnd£(String username, String password) throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Runner

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features= "src/test/java/features/login",
    glue= "stepDefinitions")

public class RunTest {
public static void main (String[] args)
{}
```

Base class (used as a global variables)

```
public class base {

public WebDriver driver;
public Properties prop;
public ChromeOptions coptions;

public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException
{
    prop= new Properties();

    String browserName= "chrome";
    System.out.println(browserName);
    String pathToDriver = "";

    if(browserName.equals("chrome"))
    {
        pathToDriver = "C:\\Repositories\\automationProject\\webDrivers\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathToDriver);
        coptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        coptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver= new ChromeDriver(coptions);
        //execute in chrome driver

    }

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

When I run the RunTest java file the below result is what I get:

Process finished with exit code 0

[File Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy5nR.png)

Comment: What JUnit version do you use? Please make sure to carefully follow the documentation, see **JUnit** section here https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/

Comment: Also describe what result do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I started to use Cucumber, it acts like the runner is not configured.

Go to run configuration and remove what was created there when you first ran your code. After this, the code will go through your RunTest, make the glue and run the feature files.

Answer (score 0):

Your runner class should not contain the main method:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features= "src/test/java/features/login",
    glue= "stepDefinitions")

public class RunTest {

}
```